# Autostart of my application in processor of Linux kernel

Tags: autostart

I am trying to run my application automatically, so I have placed a .sh that have commands to insert some modules and the path to application too in init.d folder. Then I have created a symbolic link to it and placed that in the rc3.d folder.

While I am rebooting my processor,all other commands are running except that application. How can I achieve this?

My .sh file is:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /dev/mfi-ffs/
#modprobe g_ffs idVendor=0x15A2 idProduct=0x1234 functions=fsl iSerialNumber=123456789 iManufacturer="NXP" iProduct="NXP Accessory"
#mount -t functionfs fsl /dev/mfi-ffs/
#cd /usr/bin/
#test_suite
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version? Newer versions use [systemd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/systemd); you'd put a `Foo.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system`.

Answer (score 0):

A leading `#` indicates a comment, so your script is all comments except for the `mkdir`. The script likely runs, but `test_suite` won't.

Comment: i placed it to indicate it as command

Comment: That's rather unfortunate, given that it means the **exact opposite**.

Comment: solution please

Comment: Well, remove the `#` from all commands; it only needs to be on the first line (as part of `#!`

Comment: I removed except for the first line but still its not working